# Chongqing Dialect Dictionary

Tags: topolect

Does anybody know of any Chongqing dialect dictionaries, preferably available in PDF format? I've tried to find some dictionaries but the only one I found is not available seemingly anywhere.

Comment: The  現代漢語方言大詞典 has a volume on Chengdu dialect, which covers Chongqing.

Comment: I was looking for a dictionary specific to the Chongqing dialect.

Comment: 《重庆方言志》is floating around the web in pdf format.

Comment: But this book: https://item.jd.com/12470520.html